# "Document failed to index" using the Watson Discovery tooling

Tags: watson-discovery

I need to set up a collection of Washing Machine manuals in a way that I can then set up queries against the paragraphs that are included in the manuals. My understanding is that Element Classification should help achieve that goal

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/element-classification.html#element-classification

Using the tooling, I set up a collection and uploaded the following file, selecting "Default Contract Configuration" : https://www.samsung.com/us/pdf/wf338_manual.pdf

[image: Screen shot: Document failed to index]

Why is this document upload failing?

To get more error details, I tried using the API with Postman but am unable to run the Add Document query as described here https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#add-document

[image: Screen shot: Add document via Postman]

The document is in PDF format and in text form, and is less than 50MB. 
Does anyone know what is happening or has a suggestion on how to resolve?
Thanks

Comment: Try to set the content_type as `application/pdf`.

Comment: Thank you Anton. Tried that, and I get the same 400 error. I also tried to rename from content_type to Content-Type, same error. Tried deselecting content_type in Postman (so that it does not get appended as a param to the request), same error.

Comment: Even though it is incomplete, you probably should redact your access token in the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you Jim. It is incomplete, has a short timeframe validity and no criticality so I did not bother to redact.